# Python/pandas: How to create a third DataFrame using two other boolean DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, boolean

Does anyone know how to perform the following operation with DataFrames?
I have two (or more) DataFrames consisting of columns of either strings or zeros. I would like to logically index the DataFrames so that the string is chosen over the zero. The final result here would be df_x:

```
df_a = a a a 0 0 0 a a a 0 0 0
       a a a 0 0 0 a a a 0 0 0
       a a a 0 0 0 a a a 0 0 0

df_b = 0 0 0 b b b 0 0 0 b b b
       0 0 0 b b b 0 0 0 b b b
       0 0 0 b b b 0 0 0 b b b

df_x = a a a b b b a a a b b b
       a a a b b b a a a b b b
       a a a b b b a a a b b b
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: You say "two (or more)", is it possible that you could have a situation where you need to decide between 0, "a" and "b" for a single cell value?

Comment: Thanks for asking! And no, there will be six dataframes of strings and zeros but the columns with strings should be unique for each one.